# Do something in the same thread of AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, afnetworking

I'm using Objective-C. We know AFNetworking is working in another thread, but what if I want to do something after internet request.

For example:

```
- (BOOL)checkPassword
{

    self.loginPermit = NO;

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": self.username, @"password": self.password};

    [manager POST:self.URL parameters:parameters progress:nil 
          success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        if ([[dict objectForKey:@"msg"] isEqualToString:@"00001"]){
            self.loginPermit = YES
        }
        else {
           self.loginPermit = NO;
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

    return self.loginPermit;
}
```

But it will return NO every time. How can I return the value after Internet request.

Comment: You need to do whatever you need to do in the completion block  - where you are setting the `loginPermit` property.  Probably the best way is to pass a block to the `checkPassword` method rather than have `checkPassword` return a Bool

Answer (score 0):

You should use block for this.

```
[self checkPassword:^(BOOL loginPermit) {
     if(loginPermit){
        // do your stuff
     }
 }];


- (void)checkPassword:(void(^)(BOOL loginPermit))completion
{

 BOOL loginPermit = NO;

 // show indicator

 AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
 manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
 NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": self.username, @"password": self.password};

 [manager POST:self.URL parameters:parameters progress:nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
  {
      //hide indicator

     NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
     if ([[dict objectForKey:@"msg"] isEqualToString:@"00001"]){
         loginPermit = YES;
     }
     else {
         loginPermit = NO;
     }

     completion (loginPermit);

  } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

     //hide indicator
     completion (loginPermit);
  }];
}
```

Comment: Should I declare loginPermit with __block BOOL loginPermit;